# Python if statement not working

Tags: python, file, if-statement

I have an if/else statement in python, and I want to do nothing when it goes to the else statement.

I am reading a list of words, finding the palindromes (eg 'abba') and printing them out. It **currently prints out the entire list of words**, and I know the is_palindrome function is working correctly.

```
def first(word):
    return word[0]

def last(word):
    return word[-1]

def middle(word):
    return word[1:-1]


def is_palindrome(word):
    #print(word)
    if len(word) >1:
        if first(word) == last(word):
            #print(word)
            #print(middle(word))
            return is_palindrome(middle(word))
        else:
            return False
    else:
        return True


try:
    words = open("/usr/share/dict/words","r")

    for line in words:
        line.strip()
        #print line
        if is_palindrome(line) == True:
            print(line)
    else
    words.close()
except:
    print("File open FAILED")
```

I'd appreciate any insight you could give me. Thanks.

Comment: This won't work because your indention in lines 3 and 4 from the bottom is wrong.

Comment: you have some syntax errors in this code fragment, also a bunch of commented out print statements.. maybe there is another print statement you failed to comment out?

Comment: The indentation is right on the original copy, maybe I put this in wrong.

I didn't miss any, I just needed to put line =line.strip().

Comment: I tried your code and replaced your `words = open...` with `words = ["abba", "test", ...]` and it worked.. what does your actual file look like?

Comment: @Lutz: http://psung.blogspot.de/2007/12/for-else-in-python.html

But yes, there is missing a colon after the last else and words.close() has to be indented correctly

Answer (score 9):

'line.strip()' by itself won't change line. This ought to work.

```
for line in words:
    line = line.strip()
    if is_palindrome(line) == True:
        print(line)

words.close()
```